# date with strtotime not working properly - php

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I can't get this date with strtotime function to work properly.
I need to convert the date to display to "d/m/Y".
I'm getting the date off the database correctly but it does not convert to my new date format, instead it just echoes everything with the date inside the $row[saleDate].

Here's the code:

```
    echo "<tr><td class='contentTd'> $row[saleNumber] </td>
            <td class='contentTd'> $row[saleValue] </td>
            <td class='contentTd'> $row[paymentMethod] </td>
            <td class='contentTd'> $row[sellerName] </td>
            <td class='contentTd'> date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row[saleDate])); 
            </td></tr>";
```

Could you help me out please?

Answer (score 0):

Use concatenation to show the date..

```
      echo "<tr><td class='contentTd'> $row[saleNumber] </td>
        <td class='contentTd'> $row[saleValue] </td>
        <td class='contentTd'> $row[paymentMethod] </td>
        <td class='contentTd'> $row[sellerName] </td>
        <td class='contentTd'>".' date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row[saleDate]);'. 
        "</td></tr>";
```

Comment: It gives me the same error.
I closed the date function too.

Comment: `echo "<tr><td class='contentTd'> $row[saleNumber]</td>
    <td class='contentTd'>  $row[saleValue]</td>
    <td class='contentTd'> $row[paymentMethod]</td>
    <td class='contentTd'> $row[sellerName]</td>
    <td class='contentTd'>". date('d/m/Y',strtotime($row[saleDate])) .
"</td></tr>"; `

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget closing date() function or strtotime() function

Comment: Yeah, Forgot to close.
But it gives me back the same error.

Comment: I think you must declare this on the top of file date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

Comment: No need to set timezone since the date is coming from a database.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the error: 
Missing quotes inside the strtotime function.

```
echo "<tr><td class='contentTd'> $row[saleNumber] </td>
            <td class='contentTd'> $row[saleValue] </td>
            <td class='contentTd'> $row[paymentMethod] </td>
            <td class='contentTd'> $row[sellerName] </td>
            <td class='contentTd'>" . date('d/m/Y', strtotime("$row[saleDate]")) . "</td></tr>";
```

Now it's working fine!